# Enclojure NBM file turns out to be a folder

Tags: netbeans, clojure, enclojure

I'm trying to install Enclojure. I've downloaded the latest zip file from GitHub (http://github.com/EricThorsen/enclojure/downloads), but when I unzip it, I get a folder ending in .nbm, not a file. The install directions say to point NetBeans to a .nbm *file*, not a folder, and NetBeans won't let me select the folder, either. The folder contains files and folders appropriate to a Java plugin, but I think it needs to be compressed into a single file, like a CAB in Windows. I tried downloading another NBM file from the NetBeans plugin repository, and it downloaded as one file, but for some reason it's not working with Enclojure. I don't know whether it matters, but I'm using Mac OS X Leopard.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully installed Enclojure on Mac OS X 10.5.8 + NetBeans 6.8 like this:

- sudo port install wget
- wget http://cloud.github.com/downloads/EricThorsen/enclojure/enclojure-plugin-2010-jan.nbm
- launch NetBeans, click "Install Plugins", select "Downloaded" tab, "Add Plugins..." button and find your downloaded enclojure-plugin-2010-jan.nbm file

Answer (score 1):

Don't download any of the files provided in .zip format. Download the latest release's .nbm file (`enclojure-plugin-2010-jan.nbm` currently) by clicking on its name in the table with a couple .nbm entries and a couple of .zips (which you should be able just to ignore). Then follow the rest of the instructions from [here](http://www.enclojure.org/gettingstarted).

As a side note, .nbm files are themselves just .zip archives renamed .nbm to mark them for their purpose... Perhaps if you zipped up the contents of your .nbm folder and renamed the archive to whatever.nbm, you'd have a working Enclojure (though I haven't checked). But anyway, don't do it, just grab the .nbm file straight from the source.

Comment: Actually, I have been clicking on the .nbm file, but it downloads as a .zip file (enclojure.nbm.zip for example), and when I unzip it, it unzips not only the .zip file, but also the .nbm. Just now, I tried renaming taking the .zip extension off the end of the download, and NetBeans won't let me select it (it's grayed out). This is Netbeans 6.8 on OS X Leopard. Is anyone else having a similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: That's seriously weird. Perhaps you could get the sources with git and build the thing yourself? (Instructions are provided in the file build-readme.txt; see the Source tab on github.) Or maybe you could download the file with wget (or a different browser, or from a different computer) so as to skip troubleshooting the download for now? Just so you know, you should be able to peek inside it and see Info, META-INF and netbeans directories (in fact, see if the .nbm directory you're getting when you decompress the .zip file might contain such directories; you could then repackage them properly).

Comment: Downloading it with curl worked (another poster suggested this). Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Glad you made it. Have fun with Clojure! (Note I did suggest wget in my previous comment, but whatever, I'm still happy for you. ;-))